# Python3 Stack implementation with List built-in

Tags: python, python-3.x, stack

So, inspired by [this other code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/182427/python-stack-implementation), I wanted to see if I could implement a very basic stack without the linked-list approach taken by the OP in their implementation.

To that end, I came up with the following Stack class.  I wrote it for Python 3, but it actually works as-is in Python 2 as well:

```
class Stack:
    _stack = []

    def __init__(self):
        self._stack = []

    @property
    def size(self):
        return len(self._stack)

    @property
    def count(self):
        return self.size

    def __sizeof__(self):
        return self.size

    def pop(self):
        if self.size == 0:
            return "Cannot pop from an empty stack."

        item = self._stack[self.size - 1]
        self._stack.remove(item)
        return item

    def peek(self):
        if self.size == 0:
            return "Cannot peek into an empty stack."

        return self._stack[self.size - 1]

    def push(self, item):
        self._stack.append(item)

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._stack)
```

I'm probably missing some key parts of what one would want from a Stack, but any improvement is welcome.  Literally any improvement.

**Note there were a couple things I did intentionally:**

1. I intentionally initialize the _stack attribute as an empty list both in the class itself and in `__init__`.  For some reason PyCharm complains if the attribute isn't already part of the class when being worked with in `__init__`, so this is more or less to get PyCharm to stop yelling at me.
2. I intentionally have `__sizeof__` declared as referring to the `size` property function.  This lets `len(StackObject)` work if someone doesn't want to do `stack.size`.

With these in mind, feel free to tell me what you think, or point out any mistakes I've made.  (I'm not an expert in data structures, so I may have gotten *some* points messed up a little).

Comment: `__sizeof__` is expected to [return memory size](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html?highlight=sizeof#sys.getsizeof) rather then length. I think you meant to implement `__len__` instead?

Comment: @AustinHastings addressed by Coal_'s answer, and admittedly a confusion of the special names on my part.  Properly fixed in the reviewed/altered code I'm going to put into place shortly via another review.

Comment: [Round #2 of the reviews has been posted](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/182443/python3-stack-implementation-with-list-built-in-round-two) for your consideration :)

Comment: `self._stack[self.size - 1]` could be simplified to `self._stack[-1]`

Comment: `count` seems to not fit in with other python structures such as `list` and `str` which have a `count` function which counts the number of times a specific value appears.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By far the biggest problem this code has is error handling. When popping or peeking from an empty `stack` this returns a string. **this is really broken.** For an example of why, suppose I add the string `"Cannot peek into an empty stack."` to the stack and then try to see what the top element is. I won't know if the answer I got was because the stack was empty, or because that string was in the stack. The solution to this is to `raise` an `IndexError` when the stack is empty. I also think that you shouldn't define either `size` or `count`, as the pythonic way of getting somethings length is to call `len(x)`. You might also be interested to know that python lists have a `pop` function already, so you could just use that for your `pop`

Comment: I've replaced the string return with a `raise` to raise an `IndexError` with a descriptive message.  Which is valid Python.  Didn't know the list had a `pop` function, which is *nice* to know about.  That helps reduce the `pop` function, though I kept the size check in there.  Note that other functions rely on `size` and while I could switch it to a `len(...)` call it seems like code repetition / annoyingness.  Even if I made it an internal item, someone may want to know the size of the stack using old-style calls (like the OP from the post that inspired my implementation, mind you). ...

Comment: ... but know that I do agree with you 100% though :)

Comment: @ThomasWard How is `len(self)` worse than `self.size`? It's exactly the same length, plus it's more Pythonic. `There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.` Having multiple methods and properties that do the same thing is useless code repetition (made worse by the fact that `__sizeof__` is not consistent with its intended use).

Comment: python made the decision to make `len` a function rather than to use a `size` method. This is the api that all builtin's use, and as such is the api you should use if you are writing a library for python code.

Answer (score 6):

The implementation looks pretty clean and simple to me, but here's what caught my attention:

- I think you should sacrifice PyCharm complaining about accessing attributes in `__init__` (which is very weird) for readability here. It's just one line of code, but it's pretty confusing since `_stack` is obviously bound to an instance.
- `obj.__sizeof__ != obj.__len__`, [which is really what you're supposed to override](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__len__) for `len(obj)` and `sys.getsizeof(obj)` to work as expected.

  Try this:

  ```
  >>> class Foo:
  ...     def __init__(self, x):
  ...             self.x = x
  ...     def __sizeof__(self):
  ...             return 100
  ...     def __len__(self):
  ...             return len(self.x)
  ...
  >>>
  >>> class Bar:
  ...     def __init__(self, x):
  ...             self.x = x
  ...     def __sizeof__(self):
  ...             return 200
  ...     def __len__(self):
  ...             return len(self.x)
  ...
  >>> f = Foo([1,2,3])
  >>> b = Bar([1,2,3,4])
  >>> assert len(f) == 3
  >>> assert len(b) == 4
  ```

  So far, so good. Calling `len` on instances of `Foo` and `Bar` works just fine. But what happens when we use `sys.getsizeof`?

  ```
  >>> import sys
  >>> sys.getsizeof(f)
  124
  >>> sys.getsizeof(b)
  224
  ```

  (The added 24 bytes are [garbage collector overhead](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof)).
- Functions shouldn't return an error message. I would expect `pop` and `seek` to return `None`, or throw an exception. Returning strings is dangerous, *especially in this case*, where they could be a valid return value, even if nothing went wrong.

Answer (score 4):

> I intentionally have `__sizeof__` declared as referring to the `size` property function. This lets `len(StackObject)` work if someone doesn't want to do `stack.size`.

From [The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/):

> There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.

Python likes there to be One True Way to do things, because it keeps usage consistent everywhere.

In this case, I would do away with the `size` and `count` properties entirely, and just define a `__len__` (not `__sizeof__`, like other answers have mentioned). Using `__len__` (or rather, the `len()` function) is the standard way to find the size of a container in Python, so you should provide this method and nothing else.

Instead of:

```
...

@property
def size(self):
    return len(self._stack)

@property
def count(self):
    return self.size

def __sizeof__(self):
    return self.size

...
```

Do this:

```
def __len__(self):
    return len(self._stack)
```