# Python3 Stack implementation with List built-in - Round Two

Tags: python, python-3.x, stack

> Previous code is available at [Python3 Stack implementation with List built-in](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/182435/python3-stack-implementation-with-list-built-in), this is a second-round review after I made alterations.

Once again, let's review my Stack implementation, with built-in lists, and with review notes from the prior review implemented.

Any changes and suggestions are welcome!

---

---

```
class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self._stack = []

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._stack)

    def pop(self):
        if len(self) == 0:
            raise IndexError("You cannot pop from an empty stack.")

        return self._stack.pop()

    def peek(self):
        if len(self) == 0:
            raise IndexError("You cannot peek into an empty stack.")

        return self._stack[len(self) - 1]

    def push(self, item):
        self._stack.append(item)

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._stack)
```

Comment: Shouldn't `__iter__` iterate the list in reverse order?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- If you don't care if the error is textually correct, then you can remove the if in `pop` and `peek`.
- You don't need to find the length of the stack to find the last element. You can just use `self._stack[-1]`.

Creating:

```
class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self._stack = []

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._stack)

    def pop(self):
        return self._stack.pop()

    def peek(self):
        return self._stack[-1]

    def push(self, item):
        self._stack.append(item)

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._stack)
```

From this, it begs the question why not inherit from `list`? Which would make the code:

```
class Stack(list):
    def peek(self):
        return self[-1]

    def push(self, item):
        self.append(item)
```

If you're likely to switch to another form of `Stack`, then you may want to keep with this. However, for the most part I'd recommend not using this class. As the only benefit it has over `list` is that it's likely to work with more `Stack` interfaces.

Comment: Except that you can't really implement a stack with just a pure list.  This was more an exercise than anything else, in 99.999% of all cases you hould just use a list :p

Comment: @ThomasWard If you wanted to [reinvent-the-wheel](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reinventing-the-wheel), then you should actually implement a stack, rather than interface it.

Comment: True statement.  :)  (That said, I prefer Python lists, dicts, sets, tuples, etc. depending on my need.  Trace back far enough and you'll see that someone wrote a linked-list stack implementation which was blergh, the comments on that were along the lines of "Just use a list" and then we now get to the "Don't reinvent the wheel" thing.

Comment: @ThomasWard If you "wrote a linked-list stack implementation" and tagged it as [tag:reinventing-the-wheel] then you wouldn't get 'just use `list`'.

Comment: Maybe I'm just out of date on this whole "Python" thing, but who on earth would suggest to replace a _very specific and clear_ error message with a general index-out-of-range one? Why not use the class? It expresses the intent that I want a _stack_ and _not a list_. Inheriting from `list` gives you more power than the stack implementation in the OP: don't use as a list if you want a stack. None of these suggestions strike me as having any value, excepting the cleaner last-element lookup.

Comment: @VisualMelon What benefits does using `Stack` over `list` have? Why would you pick an object that's non-standard, when [using a list is the standard in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#using-lists-as-stacks). From what you've written you only want it so that you know it's a 'stack', Python uses duck typing, we don't care about types.

Comment: @Peilonrayz first off, I must apologise for my less-than friendly tone in the first comment. Secondly, it seems I _have_ forgotten what coding in Python is like (I avoid it because of the duck typing). The benefit that `Stack` has over `list` is that it only exposes methods that are meaningful for a stack: if it is true that in Python everyone assumes a `list` rather than some abstract `Stack`, then your hands are tied if you ever wish to expose some type as a `Stack` which doesn't lend itself to being a list (e.g. indexing isn't meaningful). I'd better stay away from Python code-reviews.

Comment: @VisualMelon Duck typing just means we expect a specific interface. Here, the `list` class exposes the `stack` interface. We don't care if `list` implements more than the `stack` interface, as we're not going to use it. The only difference between Python and C# on that aspect is C# is explicit, Python's not.

Comment: @Peilonrayz I see you've done some research on me ;) C# is based nominally on type, Python is based on members. You are right that there is no harm in passing a `list` as a `stack`. I suppose if people _really_ don't care about having a reference interface (which could be defined regardless of the type system) then there is no harm in not having one, but indexing isn't a reasonable expectation for a stack, and `List` doesn't expose a `Peek` method, which isn't an unreasonable member to include in a stack. However, this has little to do with your answer, which now seems reasonable.

Comment: @VisualMelon C# is actually the only statically typed language I've ever used... :P I agree with you, about the implementation of the interface however. I guess Python just promotes indexing... I'm happy you find my answer reasonable now, :)

Comment: @Peilonrayz that works too! I do apologise, I thought I'd un-downvoted (totally a verb) a while back, but it seems I waited too long and it won't let me. (Should you make an edit of any kind, ping me and I'll rescind it). Thank you for this insightful discussion; I _really really_ dislike Python (not specifically, I just really like static nominal typing), but it's interesting and useful to know how it's really used; and despite my efforts, I'm sure to encounter it in the real world again some time ;)

Comment: @VisualMelon I've made a edit, as I was wrong. I like Python for the freedom it gives. Maybe you'll like Python when [`typing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) gets big, :)